# returning only the most recent record in dataset

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query returning data for several dates.

I want to return only record with the most recent date in the field SAPOD (the date is in fact CYYMMDD where C=0 before 2000 and 1 after 2000 and I can show this as YYYYMMDD using `SAPOD=Case when LEFT(SAPOD,1)=1 then '20' else '19' end + SUBSTRING(cast(sapod as nvarchar(7)),2,7)`)

here is my query:

```
SELECT GFCUS, Ne.NEEAN, SCDLE, SAPOD, SATCD,CUS.GFCUN, BGCFN1, 
    BGCFN2, BGCFN3, SV.SVCSA, SV.SVNA1, SV.SVNA2, SV.SVNA3, 
     SV.SVNA4, SV.SVNA5, SV.SVPZIP, SV.NONUK
FROM SCPF ACC 
    INNER JOIN GFPF CUS ON GFCPNC = SCAN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SXPF SEQ ON SXCUS = GFCUS AND SXPRIM = ''
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SVPFClean SV ON SVSEQ = SXSEQ
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BGPF ON BGCUS = GFCUS AND BGCLC = GFCLC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN NEPF NE ON SCAB=NE.NEAB and SCAN=ne.NEAN and SCAS=ne.NEAS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SAPF SA ON SCAB=SAAB and SCAN=SAAN and SCAS=SAAS
WHERE 
    (SATCD>500 and
    scsac='IV' and
    scbal = 0 and
    scai30<>'Y' and
    scai14<>'Y' and
    not exists(select * from v5pf where v5and=scan and v5bal<>0))
GROUP BY GFCUS, Ne.NEEAN, SCDLE, SAPOD, SATCD,
    CUS.GFCUN, BGCFN1, BGCFN2, BGCFN3, SV.SVCSA, 
     SV.SVNA1, SV.SVNA2, SV.SVNA3, SV.SVNA4, SV.SVNA5, SV.SVPZIP, SV.NONUK
ORDER BY MAX(SCAN) ASC, SAPOD DESC
```

I am getting results like the below where there are several transactions by a customer, and we only want to show the data of the most recent transaction:

[image: picture of results in Excel]

So how can I show just the most recent transaction? Is this a case where I should use an `OUTER APPLY` or `CROSS APPY`?

**EDIT:**

Sorry I should clarify that I need the most recent date for each of the unique records in the field `NEEAN` which is the Account number

Comment: I think All your query needs is a `LIMIT 1`. Oops SqlServer alert! `Top 1` instead.

Comment: I guess it will be `SELECT TOP 1 ...`

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected results

Comment: well, in the picture above, I want only record 2, which is the latest date.

Comment: `TOP 1` will return only 1 record

Comment: You need to include this in column list row_number() over ( partition by GFCUS order by SAPOD) as  pos  and use have a condition in where clause to return values where pos =1 , so you will get 1 latest record per customer

Comment: @Rajesh: Please would you add that as an answer, I think this will help me to get what I want (I think I need to maybe load it all into a temp table then use `pos` in the WHERE clause against the temp table)

Comment: @Philip, added my comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() as follows:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ne.NEEAN ORDER BY SAPOD DESC) AS [Row],
    GFCUS, Ne.NEEAN, SCDLE, SAPOD, SATCD,CUS.GFCUN, BGCFN1, 
    BGCFN2, BGCFN3, SV.SVCSA, SV.SVNA1, SV.SVNA2, SV.SVNA3, 
    SV.SVNA4, SV.SVNA5, SV.SVPZIP, SV.NONUK
FROM SCPF ACC 
    INNER JOIN GFPF CUS ON GFCPNC = SCAN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SXPF SEQ ON SXCUS = GFCUS AND SXPRIM = ''
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SVPFClean SV ON SVSEQ = SXSEQ
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BGPF ON BGCUS = GFCUS AND BGCLC = GFCLC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN NEPF NE ON SCAB=NE.NEAB and SCAN=ne.NEAN and SCAS=ne.NEAS
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SAPF SA ON SCAB=SAAB and SCAN=SAAN and SCAS=SAAS
WHERE 
    (SATCD>500 and
    scsac='IV' and
    scbal = 0 and
    scai30<>'Y' and
    scai14<>'Y' and
    not exists(select * from v5pf where v5and=scan and v5bal<>0)) and
    [Row] = 1
GROUP BY GFCUS, Ne.NEEAN, SCDLE, SAPOD, SATCD,
    CUS.GFCUN, BGCFN1, BGCFN2, BGCFN3, SV.SVCSA, 
     SV.SVNA1, SV.SVNA2, SV.SVNA3, SV.SVNA4, SV.SVNA5, SV.SVPZIP, SV.NONUK
ORDER BY MAX(SCAN) ASC
```

You could encapsulate this within a subquery if you don't want to return the [Row] column.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify that I need the most recent date for each of the unique records in the field `NEEAN` which is the Account number

Comment: @Philip Amended answer to use ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: I think it has to be encapsulated in a sub-query or derived table  as otherwise there is an *invalid column [Row]* compile error

Comment: please remove the code showing use 'Top 1' - then I can accept your answer as solving the problem

Comment: @Philip TOP 1 answer now removed

Answer (score 1):

you can user row_number to get top 1 row per customer

In the where clause need to return values with pos value as 1

sample query

```
row_number() over ( partition by GFCUS order by SAPOD desc) as pos
```